# Quicksort median of 3, 5, 7 elements problem

Tags: c++, quicksort, median, partition

I'am facing huge problem with quicksort alghoritm. I have to choose pivot with median of 3, 5 and 7 elements of array. I've done it for 3 elements but it is not working properly and I don't know how to remake this code alternatively to make it for median of 5 and 7 elemenets. How to choose pivot from median of more than 3 elemenets?
Please don't hate me im trying to learn.

Quicksort func:

```
void quickSort(int arr[], int low, int high)
{
    if (low < high) 
{
        int pi = partition_3(arr, low , high);
        quickSort(arr, low, pi);
        quickSort(arr, pi + 1, high);
    }
}
```

Partition:

```
int partition( int arr[], int low, int high)
{
    int pivot = arr[low];
    int i = low - 1, j = high + 1;

    while (true) { 
        do {
            i++;
        } while (arr[i] < pivot);
        do {
            j--;
        } while (arr[j] > pivot); 
        if (i >= j)
            return j;

        swap(arr[i], arr[j]);
    }
}
```

Partition median of 3:

```
int partition_3(int arr[], int low, int high)
{
    int tab[] = { low,(high -low) / 2,high };
    sort(tab, tab + 3);
    int ind = 3 / 2;
 
    int mediana = tab[ind];
    swap(arr[mediana], arr[low]);


    return partition(arr, low, high);
}
```

Comment: Median of 3 elements is exactly the same as median of 5 or 7.  Do you understand what a median value actually is?  What is preventing you from applying that logic to your program?

Comment: i understand but this func is not working properly

Comment: _Which_ "func" is not working properly?  You've asked about median of 5 and 7, and shown only your code for 3.  Isolate the specific issue and post a question with only the relevant detail.

Comment: First, the middle index between `low` and `high` is `(high + low)/2`; plus, not minus. Second, you are sorting indexes, not array elements found at those indexes. You are supposed to choose a median element, not an element at a middle index.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - or the middle position is low + (high-low)/2, which is done to avoid overflow, although there are few cases were overflow could happen.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.